# Multi File Renamer

Tags: batch-file

OK, so I have a large collection of txt files and I need to rename them 
I'm trying it this way

Option 1:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do set name=%%~nf
ren * "%name%.*"
```

Example:

> 1 - File.txt 
> 2 - File.txt 
> 3 - File.txt 
> renamer.bat

Results:

> 1 - File.txt 
> 2 - File.txt 
> 3 - File.txt 
> 3 - File.bat  the bat file gets renamed

Option 2:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do set name=%%~nf
ren "%name%.txt" "(1).txt"
```

Example:

> 1 - File.txt 
> 2 - File.txt 
> 3 - File.txt 
> renamer.bat

Results:

> (1).txt 
> 2 - File.txt 
> 3 - File.txt 
> renamer.bat

My Goal 
Results:

> (1).txt 
> (2).txt 
> (3).txt 
> renamer.bat

I know I can just highlight all right click and rename all to (1).txt

Comment: the numbers in the resulting filenames - are they to be taken from the original filename or just consecutive numbers?

Comment: Not understanding why you are not trying to rename the files within the `FOR` command execution.

Comment: @Stephan No, not from file name, just consecutive (1), to (?) File name

Comment: @Squashman so should I fix the ren ٪name٪, to %%f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just consecutive numbering, use a counter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  ECHO ren "%%f" "(!count!).txt"
)
```

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `ren` command. Remove the `ECHO` when you are sure, it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you I did try to figure that out as well with the counter, now I see what I did wrong, I removed the echo, and it worked, Once again Thank you